# How to create android service to check if user open another app

Tags: android, android-service

I want to know if its possible do that, for example an app that you press in a button and the service is on, and when you are using your device and press in Youtube app , the service can know about this.

Im trying with a service of an instant message app but i dont know how to use this with the other function.

For example:

'' startService();
'' minimize app

- User click on Youtube app.

'' The service now know that user open youtube 1 time.

And i want to know too if is possible use this service when the user turn on the device... I dont know if its possible on Android

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Not now, in a few days i post results

Answer (score 1):

To obtain app usage statistics you can use [UsageStats](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStats.html) class from [android.app.usage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/package-summary.html) package.

The new App usage statistics API allows app developers to collect statistics related to usage of the applications. This API provides more detailed usage information than the deprecated getRecentTasks() method.

To use this API, you must first declare the `android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS` permission in your manifest. The user must also enable access for this app through Settings > Security > Apps with usage access.

[Here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AppUsageStatistics) is a basic app example showing how to use App usage statistics API to let users collect statistics related to usage of the applications.